# Striped Lines in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Does anyone know how to make a line striped, kind of like a candy cane, in ggplot2?  I cannot find any suggestions online. My problem is I have two lines that overlap and I want to visualize both colors in that portion of the line.

Comment: maybe you'll find what you want with the [```ggtextures``` package](https://github.com/clauswilke/ggtextures) but I will continue to search

Comment: If the problem is overplotting of a line, you could probably set the alpha's on these lines to be less than 1 to show both lines.